# Emulate C++ namespace in Excel macro

Tags: namespaces

C++ allows to conveniently organize the code with namespaces.

Some Excel functions -like for instance NORM.DIST- seem to follow the same logic. Is there a way to emulate a namespace from a worksheet?

Thank you!

NB: I came across an article (http://bytecomb.com/organizing-code-with-namespaces-in-vba/) explaining how to achieve this from a module, but not from a worksheet. Basically, it creates a class (eg MyNamespaceClass) and then defines one global variable (myNameSpace).

Answer (score 1):

Eventually, I dropped my attempt to emulate namespaces with their convenient dot notation (eg `namespace.functionName`) and simply named all my public functions with the the same prefix (eg `prefix_functionName`).